# Issue Creating Google Calender Event with spatie/laravel-google-calendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, google-calendar-api

**Question:**

I'm trying to create an event using Laravel and Ajax, but I'm encountering an issue where nothing happens when I change the start and end dates. I've provided my code below for reference.

**Description:**

I have a Laravel controller with a **`store`** method that handles the creation of an event. When I change the start and end dates in the form, I want to use Ajax to send the data to the server and create the event. However, it's not working as expected, and I need help identifying what's going wrong.

**web.php(Route)**

```
Route::resource('event',EventController::class);
```

**EventController**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
     
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $event = $this->createEventInstance($request);
            
            // Perform other actions if needed
            
            return;
        }

    }
      
    private function createEventInstance(Request $request)
{
    $startTime = Carbon::parse($request->input('effective_period_start_date'));
    $endTime = Carbon::parse($request->input('effective_period_end_date'));

    return new Event([
        'startDateTime' => $startTime,
        'endDateTime' => $endTime
    ]);
}
```

**Blade code**

```
 <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label class="form-label">Effective Period Start date</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control effective_period_start_date" name="effective_period_start_date" value="{{@$obj->effective_period_start_date}}" {{ $disabledfield }}>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label class="form-label">Effective Period End date</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control effective_period_end_date" name="effective_period_end_date" value="{{@$obj->effective_period_end_date }}" {{ $disabledfield }}>
    </div>
  </div>


var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    var url = '/event';
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.effective_period_start_date, .effective_period_end_date').on('change', function() {
        var startDate = $('.effective_period_start_date').val();
        var endDate = $('.effective_period_end_date').val();

        if (startDate && endDate) {
            // Prepare the data to send to the server
            // var data = {// Include CSRF token
                
            //     "effective_period_start_date": startDate,
            //     "effective_period_end_date": endDate
            // };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: {
                    effective_period_start_date: startDate,
                    effective_period_end_date: endDate
                },
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }, // Send data in the request body
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log('Event created:', response);
                    // You can handle the success response here
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                    // You can handle errors here
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Issue Details:**

1. I'm using the **`store`** method in my controller to create an event.
2. I have a private method **`createEventInstance`** to prepare the event data.
3. I'm using Js and Ajax to send the data to the server when the start and end dates change.

**Expected Behavior:**

I expect the event to be created and the success response to be handled.

**Actual Behavior:**

The event is not being created, and I'm not receiving any success response.

**Questions:**

- Can you please help me identify what might be causing this issue?
- Is there anything wrong with my Ajax request or controller logic?
- Are there any specific Laravel routes or configurations I need to check?

Answer (score 0):

> here is a example for integrating google calendar with laravel
> Used package "laravel/socialite"

```
use Google\Client as GoogleClient;
use Google_Service_Calendar;

private function createEventInstance(Request $request)
{
  $client = new GoogleClient();

  //download credentials google cloud, enable google calendar API then create credentials and download
  $client->setAuthConfig(storage_path('app/google/credentials.json'));
  $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);

  $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array('curl' => array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false)));
  $client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);

  //google oauth will return this "$token" you can save it to database for future use 
  $client->setAccessToken($token);
  $client->refreshToken($tokenRefresh);

  $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

  $obj = array(
        'summary' => 'title',
        'description' => 'notes',
        'start' => [
            'dateTime' => Carbon::parse('start_date_time')->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'),
            'timeZone' => 'Australia/Sydney'
        ],
        'end' => [
            'dateTime' => Carbon::parse('end_date_time')->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'),
            'timeZone' => 'Australia/Sydney'
        ],
      );

      $service->events->insert('email', $this->makeCalendarEvent($obj));
}

private function makeCalendarEvent($arr)
{
  return new Google_Service_Calendar_Event($arr);
}
```

> Let me know if i can help you

Comment: can you guide me how can i integrate this code in the above code I mentioned as I am new into laravel so your guidance would be helpful

Comment: i think you can on very beginner level for this feature.

learn to generate token from google oauth:
https://codyrigg.medium.com/how-to-add-a-google-login-using-socialite-on-laravel-8-with-jetstream-6153581e7dc9

talk to me personally will help you with this.